Could not be inferred wrapping callback parameter
Problem is Position. If I use primitive parameter like String, Int, works fine.
I don't understand why compiler can't infer 'Content'.
Section(items: items) { params in
  Text(params.text)
}

Source
public struct Section<T, Content>: View where T: Identifiable & Equatable, Content: View {


  public enum Position: String {
    case first
    public var text: String {
      return "text in position"
    }
  }

  var items: [T]
  @ViewBuilder var content: (Position) -> Content

  public var body: some View {
    ForEach(items) { item in
      content(.first)
    }
  }

}


Because the Position enum is declared within the Section. If you notice, when you try to implicitly infer a Text in this circumstance, the compiler cannot determine what is Content.
Section(items: items) { params in
  Text(params.text)
}

//param: Section<SomeData, _>.Position //<- `_` here

Trying to move the Position declaration outside of Section will fix this:
public enum Position: String {    
    case first
    public var text: String {
        return "text in position"
    }
}

public struct Section<T, Content>: View where T: Identifiable & Equatable, Content: View {
    ...
}

And then you're able to do this:
Section(items: items) { params in
  Text(params.text)
}

//param: Position //<- Now it's only Position

